# Selecionar itens específicos dentro de um loop while

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho o seguinte HTML dentro de um `while` PHP:

```
<article data-id="1">...</artcile>
<article data-id="2">...</artcile>
<article data-id="3">...</artcile>
<article data-id="4">...</artcile>
<article data-id="5">...</artcile>
<article data-id="6">...</artcile>
<article data-id="7">...</artcile>
<article data-id="8">...</artcile>
<article data-id="9">...</artcile>
<article data-id="10">...</artcile>
<article data-id="11">...</artcile>
<article data-id="12">...</artcile>
<article data-id="13">...</artcile>
<article data-id="14">...</artcile>
<article data-id="..."></artcile>
```

Gostaria com PHP selecionar resultados especificos dentro do loop:

```
1, 4, 7, 10, 13 ...
```

Seria selecionar `3n+1` exatamente.

Comment: Já tens alguma coisa feita?

Comment: @CesarMiguel consegui fazer com que <article> recebesse `data-id++` ou seja, que fosse incrementado +1 a cada loop. Ficou como escrito no código acima. @Bacco, "selecionar" está fazendo referência a este link -> http://catalogos.axitech.com.br> aonde as imagens destacadas recebem tamanhos diferentes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por exemplo:

```
$i = 0;
while .... {
   if ( $i++ % 3 == 0 ) {
      // selecionado
   } else {
      // não selecionado
   }
}
```

Ou mesmo:

```
$i = 0;
while .... {
   echo '<article data-id="..."'.( $i++ % 3 == 0 ? ' class="selected"' : '' ).'>...</article>'
}
```

> Para mudar o *offset* do selecionado inicial basta mudar o valor inicial de `$i`.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente como você pode ver neste link http://catalogos.axitech.com.br ... Obrigado.